# Facebook php sdk / saving users sports / array to string conversion

Tags: php, arrays, json, facebook, string

I am trying to save the sports that a user has liked on Facebook to a database. This code is part of my Facebook login, I am using laravel.

$me contains all the user data that I receive from Facebook.

```
if (array_key_exists('sports', $me)){


                    $test = $me['sports'];

                    $json = strval($test); PROBLEM HERE

                    $data = json_decode($json, true);
                    $sports = array();
                    foreach ($data as $item) {
                        $sports[] = $item['name'];
                    }

                    $user->fb_sports = $sports;
                }
```

My problem is that I am getting an array to string conversion. I am trying to convert the content of the $test variable to a string for the code that follows to work properly.

However, I don't really know what to do.

```
$me['sports']
```

returns

```
[{"id":"108124505876479","name":"Wakeboarding"},{"id":"112003352149145","name":"Bouldering"},{"id":"110008522357035","name":"Handball"}]
```

However, for my code to work properly I would need it to return this **(notice the ' and ' )**:

```
'[{"id":"108124505876479","name":"Wakeboarding"},{"id":"112003352149145","name":"Bouldering"},{"id":"110008522357035","name":"Handball"}]'
```

Is there any way to fix this? I simply want to save those sports to a database. Am I maybe choosing a completely wrong way here?

Any help would be much appreciated.

Thanks.

**EDIT:**

When I try this:

```
$sports = array();

foreach($me['sports'] as $sport){
     // save the name i.e.
     $sports[] = $sport['name'];
}
 //saving array                 
 $user->fb_sports = $sports;
```

I get this:

[image]

Comment: You can not get that (new) error message from the code you have shown … `preg_replace` is not even used in there.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I assume you're using the PHP SDK of Facebook. This class already converts the JSON string to a PHP array. That's why "$me['sports']" is an array.

There are several options to save these sports to your database.

Do you want to save all the sports separately or all together in one string?

If you would like to save them separately you need to loop:

```
foreach($me['sports'] as $sport){
    // save the name i.e.
    your_save_function($sport['name']);
}
```

If you want to save all the sports together in one string I would suggest taking a look into the [serialize](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.serialize.php) function.

```
$serializedString = serialize($me['sports']);
```

To use the array again you need to get it from the database and [unserialize](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.unserialize.php) it.

Another option is to convert the array to a JSON string again and save this.

```
$jsonString = json_encode($me['sports']);
your_save_function($jsonString);
```

If you want to use it as an array again you need to get it from the database and convert the JSON string to an array.

```
$sports = json_decode($your_db_array['sports']);
```

As you can see there are several ways. Maybe you can explain what you would like to do with the data as soon you saved it into the database, so I can help you choosing the best way.

Comment: wow! what an awesome answer. Thanks! I will definitely mark it as correct. However, I just have one issue. I tried to save only the sports name to my database. Saving the serializedString worked fine.

I have edited the question one more time with the error I get now.

Comment: Can you show us some more code? Where do you declare $user?